# PySimpleGUI how to run a perform_long_operation function that returns a value

Tags: python, multithreading, pysimplegui

just started learning and using PySimpleGUI. So far, everything works.
I have a method that trains an AI and returns the model:

```
model = train_model()
```

As this method takes a while, I use the `window.perform_long_operation(lambda: train_model(), "modelTrained")` function

However, I can not find a way to run it **and** return a value.
I have tried this:

```
model = window.perform_long_operation(lambda: train_model(), "modelTrained")
```

and this:

```
window.perform_long_operation(lambda: model = train_model(), "modelTrained")
```

Is there a way to run a method via `perform_long_operation()` that also returns a value?

Comment: "modelTrained" is the end key or event will be generated when your long operation end. To return a `value` from your long operation, just call `return value` when end of your function, then get it by `values["modelTrained"]` in your event loop. refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Long_Operations.py

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the Cookbook explains the steps to use this method as well as how to get your return value:
https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/#pysimplegui-windowperform_long_operation

The docstring for the method also has the same information.  You can see the docstring in your IDE, through the built-in SDK reference, and in the call reference in the documentation http://Calls.PySimpleGUI.org

[image]

Comment: I checked the Cookbook and found the explanation. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You bet!  I believe I saw it today while updating the main documentation.  In addition to the table of contents along the left edge, a simple Control+F is a great way to search through the different parts of the documentation.  You'll get several hits on broad term like "return value", but they're easy to traverse by pressing F3 over and over until you get to the one that fits.  Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer to this question can be put in an easy way for others to catch it quickly. So here it is:

In the event loop of the PySimpleGUI window, this is the way to manage long operations with returned values:

```
"....."
elif event == "-LONG_OPERATION_TRIGGER-":
    window.perform_long_operation(func_that_returns_a_value, '-RETURN_TRIGGER-')
elif event == "-RETURN_TRIGGER-": # This line will be entered when the long operations ends
    returned_value = values['-RETURN_TRIGGER-'] # Here you retrieve the returned value
"....."
```